# How to find Amazon EC2 AMI only have the id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

What I have is AMI id (something like this ami-06358f49b5839867c) 
The case was AMI i see in this [Karamel script](https://github.com/logicalclocks/karamel-chef/blob/master/cluster-defns/aws.1.hopsworks.yml)

How do I find information about that AMI like Name, Region, ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [describe-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html), assuming the AMI is in the default region:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-06358f49b5839867c
```

Otherwise you can specify the region, e.g.:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-06358f49b5839867c --region eu-west-1
```

If you don't know the region where the AMI lives, then you'll have to use a loop to iterate over all AWS regions. In bash, this could look like:

```bash
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].RegionName' --output text | tr '\t' '\n')
do 
  aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-06358f49b5839867c --region "$region" &>/dev/null; 
  if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; 
    then echo "AMI found in region ${region}!" && break
  fi 
done
```